# Computer Vision - Image Fundamentals

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, graphics, computer-vision, deep-learning

I have recently got hooked up on `Deep Learning in Computer Vision` and i was wondering if any of you could recommend some resources on Image Fundamentals so i understand how Images work and `Image Preprocessing`. Also if you guys have any good resources on `Deep Learning in Computer Vision` that would be great too. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Questions asking for recommendations of off-site resources are not permitted on StackOverflow.

Comment: `Code formatting` is for code, not emphasis.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Udacity has great free online courses , I'm learning computer vision there and I'm loving every moment

I highly recommend that you check them out at:
www.udacity.com